# Can't answer phone call if connected with both ethernet and wifi

Tags: macos, iphone, wifi, facetime, ethernet

I have followed all the steps listed on: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209456

Works fine if I'm only connected to either ethernet OR wifi, if I have both connections active (even tho they are the same network), I can't answer calls phone with the error: "Call Failed"

And I can't just disable WiFi and lose AirDrop/etc neither disconnect the ethernet cable and lose speed/stability.

Any options?

**Edit:** Found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150994/calls-from-yosemite-via-iphone-fail-when-connected-via-wifi-and-thunderbolt-ethe) 5 years old question, but it doesn't have a solution.

Comment: In System Preferences > Network, which protocol is first in the list using the Set Service Order command in the Settings (Gear) dropdown menu?

Comment: 1- Ethernet (Belkin USB-C LAN), 2- WiFI

Comment: I know you want to keep the ethernet as #1 for max speed, but what happens when you swap positions?

Comment: Same thing. "Call Failed"